# Comparing multidimensional arrays without the order or key match

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm updating a MySQL database table with the third-party RESTful API data. This update triggers several times a day, so to make the process easier, I decided to simply truncate the database table before inserting the new, "fresh" API data. However, this has caused two major issues:

a) the table becomes empty while the process is executing (this is a live site),

b) the MySQL server sometimes fails to truncate the table, all while the insert gets executed. This results in records being duplicated, sometimes even quadrupled.

I could place truncating and inserting into one MySQL transaction, however that still doesn't solve problem (a).

I decided to approach the problem differently:

First I collect both the API data and the local data into two identically structured arrays, sorted by key (ASC) and value (ASC). Here's an example:

```
$local = [
    ['categoryId' => '547d8fd5','programId' => '0714f2cb'],
    ['categoryId' => '547d8fd5','programId' => '0914f2cb'],
]

$remote = [
    ['categoryId' => '547d8fd5','programId' => '0714f2cb'],
    ['categoryId' => '547d8fd5','programId' => '0814f2cb'],
]
```

I'll then compare the two arrays using the following method:

```
public static function arrayDiffAssocRecursive($array1, $array2)
    {
        foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (!isset($array2[$key])) {
                    $difference[] = $value;
                } elseif(!is_array($array2[$key])) {
                    $difference[] = $value;
                } else {
                    $new_diff = self::arrayDiffAssocRecursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                    if ($new_diff != FALSE) {
                        $difference[] = $array1[$key];
                    }
                }
            } elseif (!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value) {
                $difference[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return !isset($difference) ? null : $difference;
    }
```

To get the records that need to be added, I'll call the above method using arguments in the following order:

```
$add = Comparator::arrayDiffAssocRecursive($remote, $local);
```

And to get the records that need to deleted, I'll flip the arguments:

```
$delete = Comparator::arrayDiffAssocRecursive($local, $remote);
```

The method works as long as both arrays are sorted equally and have the same number of records, however if one or the other is missing one or more records, all the remaining records will be mismatched and therefore marked for deletion and addition, regardless if they have remained the same. This method works, but I still find it to be inefficient.

What I would like to see instead is a method that can compare the two arrays and return the mismatched records regardless of the arrays' order or the total number of records. Is that doable or am I approaching this completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `json_encode()` to flatten the second level array elements into strings. Then I used `array_diff()` to to collect the unmatched elements, and finally I used `json_decode()` to return both `$add` and `$delete` arrays to their original state.

Now I no longer have to worry about matching the two arrays by ASC order or their keys, because `array_diff()` will spot the different elements regardless where they are located.

If you wonder why I used json encoding/decoding vs serialize/unserialize - according to another stackoverflow thread, json performs faster.

```
class ComparatorTest extends TestCase
{
    private $arrayA;
    private $arrayB;
    private $expectedA;
    private $expectedB;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->arrayA = [
            ['key1' => '000','key2' => '8989'],
            ['key1' => '123','key2' => '354'],
            ['key1' => 'aaa','key2' => 'sbbb'],
        ];

        $this->arrayB = [
            ['key1' => '123','key2' => '354'],
            ['key1' => 'aaa','key3' => 'asdf'],
            ['key1' => '654','key2' => '8989'],
        ];

        $this->expectedA = [
            ['key1' => '000','key2' => '8989'],
            ['key1' => 'aaa','key2' => 'sbbb']
        ];

        $this->expectedB = [
            ['key1' => 'aaa','key3' => 'asdf'],
            ['key1' => '654','key2' => '8989'],
        ];
    }

    public function testArrayDiffAssocRecursive()
    {
        $a = $this->flattenSecondLevelArray($this->arrayA);
        $b = $this->flattenSecondLevelArray($this->arrayB);

        $addFlat = array_diff($a, $b);
        $deleteFlat = array_diff($b, $a);

        $add = [];
        if (!empty($addFlat)) {
            foreach($addFlat as $row) {
                $add[] = json_decode($row, true);
            }
        }

        $delete = [];
        if (!empty($deleteFlat)) {
            foreach($deleteFlat as $row) {
                $delete[] = json_decode($row, true);
            }
        }

        $this->assertEquals($this->expectedA, $add);
        $this->assertEquals($this->expectedB, $delete);
    }

    private function flattenSecondLevelArray($array)
    {
        $flat = [];
        if(!empty($array) && is_array($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $pair) {
                $flat[] = json_encode($pair);
            }
        }
        return $flat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replace into instead of insert into. As long as you have a non-changing primary key then it will update based on the primary key. If the primary key already exists, it does an update else it does an insert.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, however that would work only for updating and creating records. I would still need to find and remove orphaned records (no longer active in the API data)?

Comment: Faster to create another table, do your inserts there. Once that's done, drop the existing table and then rename this new table.